# /dev/dsp missing in debian and cannot hear festival utterance

Tags: linux, bash, debian, dev, speech

Tried to make an utterance in festival and it seems /dev/dsp/ is missing in the debian. How to add this?

```
festival> (SayText "Hello")
Linux: can't open /dev/dsp
#<Utterance 0xb669c708>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with a TV tuner card. Here is what to do:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils alsa-oss
```

Comment: in debian after installin alsa and oss the snd-pcm-oss has to be loaded.
modprobe snd-pcm-oss

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to run the desired software using `padsp`, which is an OSS wrapper for Pulse Audio.

Simply run:

```
padsp festival
```

Note that it will use the default audio devices which you can change with your system's audio settings utility.

Comment: There is no need to post two answers to the same question. You may very well edit the first one, and as an edit the second possible solution.